# Name Error: Angular/Rails Alternative Controller Method Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, json

I want to access the json for upvote in the browser like  http://localhost:3000/groups.json (see code). Not having much luck, here is the relevant code.

Error: undefined local variable or method `group_params' for #

```
// inject $http so we can go to http://localhost:3000/groups.json in our browser and see an array of all the groups in our database
.factory('groups', ['$http', function($http){
    //service body
    var o = {
        groups: []
    };

    // get all the groups in the service, groups.js
    o.getAll = function() {
      return $http.get('/groups.json').success(function(data){
        angular.copy(data, o.groups);
      });
    };


    o.getAll = function() {
      return $http.get('/groups/upvote.json').success(function(data){
        angular.copy(data, o.groups);
      });
    };
```

Rails Controller:

```
   before_action :set_group, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :upvote]

  def upvote
    @groups = Group.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {}
      format.json { render json: @groups }
    end
  end
```

Additional Methods:

```
  def index
   @groups = Group.all

   respond_to do |format|
     format.html {}
     format.json { render json: @groups }
   end
  end      

 def set_group
     @group = Group.where(params[:id])
  end
```

Full Error:

```
Started GET "/groups/upvote.json" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-03-21 21:37:22       0700
Processing by GroupsController#show as JSON
Parameters: {"id"=>"upvote"}
  Group Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "groups".* FROM "groups" WHERE     "groups"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 0]]
Completed 404 Not Found in 5ms (ActiveRecord: 2.4ms)

ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Group with 'id'=upvote):
  app/controllers/groups_controller.rb:131:in `set_group'
```

Comment: You're calling the `set_group` as a `before_action` for `upvote`, which is where I'm guessing the problem is. Can you please show the code for that method as well?

Comment: Added, the method is set the same way. It works for the index action with out problems.

Comment: Ah, so definitely not that. Can you also share the full stacktrace of the exception?

Comment: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Is what I am getting on the console. It is what I suspected the json is not being located so it must be a routing issue? 

I also checked the paths in the rails c. There is no path, so it must be adding a custom path for the json. I am retrieving a collection and want it accessible through route that will spit it out.....hmmm

Comment: Wait, what if I made a controller specific to the task....

Comment: So the reason that you're having is that `set_group` can't find a record with the given id (which I'm guessing is `nil`) in this case, which also doesn't match up with the code you posted. Since you don't need the group to be set for your `upvote` route, you can take that off the list in `before_action`, which should render your json properly

Comment: Oh that sounds promising.

Comment: Added  and followed the advice. Do you want to post solution and I will accept?

 collection do
    get 'upvote'
  end ... did the trick

Comment: Awesome, thanks @McDoku

Answer (score 1):

To summarise our chat in comments:

According to the stacktrace the error is caused by the `set_group` method throwing a `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound` exception which in turn results in the endpoint returning a 404, although the code snippet posted in the question for `set_group` does not exactly match that.

Since the `upvote` action does not require `@group` to be set you can simply remove `upvote` from the list of actions in `before_action`.

Comment: wait no this was not the solve. I used a collection inside the group resource in router.rb making the JSON available through http://localhost:3000/groups/upvote.json to the AngApp